# What is it like to be a Twitch chess streamer?

Tags: online-chess, chess-videos

I want to make a Twitch stream channel with my friend, and I want to know what the experience is like. Can explain it better to me or share their knowledge and experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be interesting to know what your goals with the channel will be. If it is to have enough revenue that it can become your job, you will need to offer something that others are not already offering, or do what they are doing a lot better. You need some kind of "angle".

For most chess channels, the angle is that they are Grandmasters, and since I looked you up on FIDE.com for another question previously, I know that you are far from that (I am not trying to be mean there). The other channels that are very popular by weak players also have something in common: Cute girls with good personalities. Alexandra Botez and Gold Dust Tori come to mind. Frankly, Tori is so weak, I could not imagine watching her although I have seen her for a few minutes here or there when a chess.com broadcast I was watching ended, and my channel was "raided" (users that are automatically transferred to another channel). Be prepared to change your approach after some time if you not getting any followers.

I am not saying that you cannot do it, but you will need to find something that makes you very unique. One idea for someone else might be: If you had been about half your age, like 6, it could have been to follow the little boy from novice through to Grandmaster, and grow with him. You are considering trying to stream with a partner. Partners seem to do well here (and on radio and television). A partner allow for more conversation, and for you to bounce things off each other.

Once you have your idea, then there is patience, and promotion. Assuming that you want to make money (if just for fun to have a channel, then all bets are off...just have fun), you would need to understand that it would be a job. You will need to spend many hours streaming for little, or no, money in the beginning until you have a following. Unlike YouTube, Twitch is more about live playing against various opponents, and you discussing what it going on for the audience.

Did I mention that it is a job? (Yes, I know I did.) You would need to take it seriously, and be consistent about your streaming, and that means probably every day, 7 days a week in the beginning. Famous streamers, like Hikaru Nakamura, can take stream as they like since people will show up when they show up (Naka puts his schedule on Twitter, for example).

Promotion. You will need to learn how to promote your channel via social media so people can find you among the multitude of channels. You will need to read books and websites from experts on how to do that. I do not know much about this, but you would need to find out how the system for "raids" works. That might be about building personal relationships, aka partnerships, so established channels are willing to let you take their audience when they are done.

It is a numbers game: You will need follower first, and then maybe they can turn into subscribers. Not all subscriptions cost money since Amazon owns Twitch, and they allow Prime members one free subscription per month. I usually back chess.com or Naka, personally with my Prime membership.

I wish you good luck if you try to do this.

["Tips for becoming a Twitch video game streamer"](https://www.axs.com/tips-for-becoming-a-twitch-video-game-streamer-134521)

Answer (score -3):

For too many it feels like spewing streams into the void with nobody watching.
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17541600

Just how many people are out there watching at all?
How many streamers are there?

So how does it feel to stream stuff into the great bit bucket of the cosmos?  That strictly depends on you and your psychological problems.

Personally I would feel stupid wasting my time doing it.

Twitch.tv is a video-game broadcasting and viewing platform where viewers can "donate" to their favorite players. ... Video game players broadcast themselves playing the game, usually with an audio commentary.

I would feel more stupid wasting my money on it.

Do I have to pay for twitch?
Select Subscribe | $4.99 to choose the default monthly subscription fee of $4.99 USD. Or, pick All Paid Tiers to choose the $9.99 or $24.99 payment option and see a list of perks for each subscription tier.Jul 1, 2019